# What is the Optimal way to handle Children of a UWP Templated Control?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

This works but seems a bit kludgy. Repo:[ThemeWrap1](https://github.com/groovykool/ThemeWrap1.git)

I use a grid in the constructor to get a UIElementcollection and then after the template is applied I move the children to the BaseG grid in the template.

...Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="local:Wrap">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeHighBrush}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Wrap">
                <Grid x:Name="BaseG"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...

...Wrap.cs

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Children")]
public sealed class Wrap : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Children),
      typeof(UIElementCollection),
      typeof(Wrap),
      new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public UIElementCollection Children
    {
        get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ChildrenProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value); }
    }

    public Wrap()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Wrap);
        //instance Grid to get a UIElementCollection.  UIElementCollection has no exposed constructor.
        Grid tempgrid = new Grid();
        Children = tempgrid.Children;
        tempgrid = null;
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        //Get the Template Grid and Move the Children.
        if (GetTemplateChild("BaseG") is Grid gd)
        {             
            var clist = Children.ToList();
            Children.Clear();
            foreach (var item in clist)
            {
                gd.Children.Add(item);
            }
            Children = gd.Children;
        }
    }
}
```

...

Comment: There is no better way to get a UIElementCollection instance.

Comment: Typically if you *require* children you could inherit from ItemsControl instead, or an ItemsRepeater. If you're a panel with only layout logic, you should inherit Panel instead, otherwise your templated control should just host content in a ContentPresenter and not care about its children, unless there's an explicit reason you need the direct reference to children?

Comment: In your example repo however, it's worth noting that setting `RequestedTheme` on any element automatically propagates down the VisualTree to child elements, so in this case the custom control doesn't seem necessary. Having a grid directly on the page and setting RequestedTheme on that should have the same result.

Comment: This case is more related to WinUI. The WinUI team is actively answering WinUI questions in [WinUI GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues). You may get a better solution there.

Comment: RequestedTheme only works if the FrameworkElement has a Template.    Grid does not.  If I want a Grid or other panel with a themed background, I need to wrap the Grid with a templated Control.  https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4389